# jQuery can not change attribute of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text and src of vedio using jQuery it seems I can not get it in the first place

My html markup:

```
<section class="main-section">
        <!-- Add Your Content Inside -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        @{
                            var tst = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + @Model.First().Lessons.First().lessonsVedio;
                        }
                        <iframe id="theVedio" class="embed-responsive-item" src=@tst allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div>
                        <p id="theText">tetttttststststtsbsjdbs,dbvskdvbksdbvksdbvs</p>
                    </div>
                    <a id="theMatherial" href="" class="btn btn-primary">Material</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </section>
```

My jQuery code*:

This is the part which has the problem

```
success: function (data) {
                alert("jQuery success");
                    alert(data[0]);
                    alert(data[1]);
                    alert(data[2]);
                    $("#thevedio").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data[0] + "?autoplay=1");
                    $("#thetext").text(data[1]);
                    $("#thematherial").attr('href', data[2]);
                    console.log($("#thevedio").attr("src"));
                    $("#thevedio").load();
                    $("#thetext").load();

                //alert(data.text);

            }
```

I was testing with alerts and it have the needed strings, but when I use console.log it output undefined.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Because case matters v != V along with the rest of the lower case letters in the ids that are capitals in the mark up.

Comment: oh that is really strange most of the time i just copy and paste them seems i need to sleep thanks and sorry

Comment: What are you using to pre-process your HTML?

Comment: it is asp.net mvc , and it is razor which pre process the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery identifiers are case sensitive so the case needs to match the HTML element.

For example:

```
$("#theMatherial").attr('href', data[2]);
```

Full function:

```
success: function (data) {
            alert("jQuery success");
                alert(data[0]);
                alert(data[1]);
                alert(data[2]);
                $("#theVedio").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data[0] + "?autoplay=1");
                $("#theText").text(data[1]);
                $("#theMatherial").attr('href', data[2]);
                console.log($("#theVedio").attr("src"));
                $("#theVedio").load();
                $("#theText").load();

            //alert(data.text);

        }
```